# R For a list Generate all combinations of factor, all combinations of merges, and combine

Tags: r, merge, split, combinations, reduce

So i am working with cancer stage data. Assume a dataset of this type. Its a dataframe.

```
   cancertype     stage
TCGA-67-6215-01     1
TCGA-67-6216-01     1
TCGA-67-6217-01     2
TCGA-69-7760-01     2
TCGA-69-7761-01     1
TCGA-69-7763-01     1
TCGA-69-7764-01     1
TCGA-69-7765-01     4
TCGA-69-7980-01     1
TCGA-71-6725-01     1
TCGA-73-4658-01     1
TCGA-73-4659-01     3
TCGA-73-4662-01     1
TCGA-73-4675-01     3
```

So what I want is a list where each element is a dataframe. Here there are 4 levels for the 4 possible cancer stages. There should be dataframe for each combo of 2 levels, of 3 levels,etc up to the # of levels in the data. But also a dataframe for each combination of merged levels. What i mean is

```
list(
dataframe of stage1 and 2
dataframe of stage1 and 3
dataframe of stage 1 and 4
dataframe of stage 2 and 3
...etc
dataframe of stage 1,2 and 3
dataframe of stage 2,3 and 4
...
dataframe of stage 1,2 and 3,4
dataframe of stage 1,3 and 2,4
dataframe of stage 1,2,3 and 4
dataframe of stage 1,2,4 and 3
.. etc etc I think this should give you the idea.
)
```

Here when I say stage 1,2,4 I mean they have all been merged to one level.

I basically am trying to do every possible comparison of a t-test, so I am setting up the samples I will need for this comparison. It would be nice to just do every possible combo and merge combo.

Where I am so far, I am able to combine all the elements of unmerged comparisons
which is 11 . i.e. 6 combos of 2 stages, 4 combos of 3 stages, 1 combo of 4 stages

```
stage # dataframe of stage data as factors
stage_split <-split(stage,stage[,1])
allcombos<- c(combn(stage_split,2,simplify=F), combn(stage_split,3,simplify=F), combn(stage_split,4,simplify=F))
allcombos_cmbnd<- lapply(allcombos, function(x) Reduce(rbind,x))
```

How do I do I generate the additional dataframes from all the possible merge permutations, and then append to this list? Maybe there is an elegant way from the first dataframe to accomplish this. One way would be to iterate through this list of 11 and generate merge starting at combos of 3? I could brute force it but I am hoping there is an elegant way to perform this that could be scaled up. Nothing I found so far explains how to do generate all combinations of  levels in your data and all merge combinations of your levels.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you show us an example of some of the combinations? @user227710's comment would, for example `expand.grid(list(1:3,1:4))`

Answer (score 2):

When you are grouping the stages together, you are partitioning sets of size 3 or 4.  There is a package, `partitions` that implements set partitioning with `setparts`.  Here I focus on that merging part, since it sounds like you already figured out the non-merged grouping.

```
 ## For unmerged, get groupings with something like this
combos <- unlist(lapply(2:4, function(x) combn(unique(dat$stage), x, simplify=F)), rec=F)

## For merged groupings, use set partitioning
library(partitions)
dats <- unlist(sapply(3:4, function(p) {
    parts <- setparts(p)  # set partitions of size p
    lst <- lapply(split(parts, col(parts)), function(idx) {
        if (p==3) {       # with sets of 3, need to exclude one of the stages
            subLst <- lapply(1:4, function(exclude) {
                tmp <- dat$stage
                tmp[dat$stage==exclude] <- NA
                ids <- seq(4)[-exclude]
                for (i in 1:3) tmp[dat$stage==ids[i]] <- idx[i]
                data.frame(dat$cancertype, stage=tmp)
            })
            names(subLst) <- paste(1:4)
            subLst
        } else {          # sets of 4, no need to exclude
            tmp <- dat$stage
            for (i in 1:length(idx)) tmp[dat$stage==i] <- idx[i]
            data.frame(dat$cancertype, stage=tmp)
        }
    })
    names(lst) <- lapply(split(parts, col(parts)), paste, collapse=".")
    lst
}), rec=F)
```

`dats` is now a list of `data.frames` with the `stage`s grouped by the set partitions.  When partitioning sets of size 3, one of the stages had to be removed.  So, those entries in `dats` appear as lists of length four, each element corresponding to removing a stage from consideration (the lists are ordered, so the first component removes stage 1, the second removes stage 2, etc).  Lets look at one or the size 3 partitions,

```
dats[4]
$`2.1.1`
# $`2.1.1`$`1`
#     dat.cancertype stage
# 1  TCGA-67-6215-01    NA
# 2  TCGA-67-6216-01    NA
# 3  TCGA-67-6217-01     2
# 4  TCGA-69-7760-01     2
# 5  TCGA-69-7761-01    NA
# 6  TCGA-69-7763-01    NA
# 7  TCGA-69-7764-01    NA
# 8  TCGA-69-7765-01     1
# 9  TCGA-69-7980-01    NA
# 10 TCGA-71-6725-01    NA
# 11 TCGA-73-4658-01    NA
# 12 TCGA-73-4659-01     1
# 13 TCGA-73-4662-01    NA
# 14 TCGA-73-4675-01     1
# 
# $`2.1.1`$`2`
#     dat.cancertype stage
# 1  TCGA-67-6215-01     2
# 2  TCGA-67-6216-01     2
# 3  TCGA-67-6217-01    NA
# 4  TCGA-69-7760-01    NA
# 5  TCGA-69-7761-01     2
# 6  TCGA-69-7763-01     2
# 7  TCGA-69-7764-01     2
# 8  TCGA-69-7765-01     1
# 9  TCGA-69-7980-01     2
# 10 TCGA-71-6725-01     2
# 11 TCGA-73-4658-01     2
# 12 TCGA-73-4659-01     1
# 13 TCGA-73-4662-01     2
# 14 TCGA-73-4675-01     1
```

The naming convention here is `group1.group2.group3$excludedGroup`, and identical numbers means the groups have been merged.  So, `2.1.1$1` means the first group has been excluded (`$1`, actually just converted to `NA`) and in the remaining data, groups 2 and 3 have been combined.  It's a bit confusing and a better naming scheme is probably need.  As an example, `$2.1.1$1` means "stage 1 is excluded (NA) and stage 3 and stage 4 have been combined".  So, I could access that data with `dats[['2.1.1']][['1']]`.  There are two more data.frames in this list that aren't shown (those excluding stages 3 and 4).

Now, the set-4 partitions are more straightforward since there were no exclusions.  For example,

```
dats[19]
# $`2.3.1.1`
#     dat.cancertype stage
# 1  TCGA-67-6215-01     2
# 2  TCGA-67-6216-01     2
# 3  TCGA-67-6217-01     3
# 4  TCGA-69-7760-01     3
# 5  TCGA-69-7761-01     2
# 6  TCGA-69-7763-01     2
# 7  TCGA-69-7764-01     2
# 8  TCGA-69-7765-01     1
# 9  TCGA-69-7980-01     2
# 10 TCGA-71-6725-01     2
# 11 TCGA-73-4658-01     2
# 12 TCGA-73-4659-01     1
# 13 TCGA-73-4662-01     2
# 14 TCGA-73-4675-01     1
```

The naming here is "Group1.Group2.Group3.Group4".  In this grouping stage 3 and 4 have been merged for example (both == 1).

There are redundancies here, you could either go with partitioning sets or size 3 with exclusion or partitioning sets of size 4 and doing multiple comparisons on each `data.frame`.  For example, of the datasets shown above, equivalent tests can be done using `dats[['2.3.1.1']]` or both `dats[['2.1.1']][['1']]` and `dats[['2.1.1']][['2']]` combined.

To simplify things, instead of storing all these `data.frame`s in a list you could just store the indices, or just do your calculations in the loop.

Comment: Thanks so much! Amazing what you came up with so quickly. It's an interesting question to me to generalize it for any size in an efficient manner. It seems to be the sum of the bell #s of the set and every subset. I still feel like there must be a more elegantish way to get at this. I dont know what it is though!